# What the way that I can tick message checkbox in gmail?

Tags: selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to select messages with particular subject in gmail using selenium.
Code:

```
var element = driver.FindElements(By.XPath("//tr[contains(@class,'zA yO') or contains(@class,'zA zE')]")); //select message line
foreach (var chbox in element)
{
    if (chbox.FindElement(By.XPath(//span[contains(".,'subjecttext')]")).Displayed) //Filter message line by subject text
    {
        chbox.FindElement(By.ClassName("T-Jo-auh")).Click(); //Click on checkbox
    }
    else 
    {
        continue;
    }
}
```

But this code tick checkbox on all messages. Can someone explain me how to click on filtered checkbox?

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because your below XPath is returning all checkbox

```
//tr[contains(@class,'zA yO') or contains(@class,'zA zE')]
```

You need to identify the locator for that respective checkbox only.

If you want to click only on one checkbox then you do not need to use above code.
While if you want to click on first checkbox only then use `break;` so that the loop stop in first iteration itself

Hope it will help you

Comment: Question is how to identify this locator? Under identifying element I use another filter //span that doesn't actually filter elements, I think. Should I use xpath siblings? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

found locator

```
//tr[contains(@class,'zA yO') or contains(@class,'zA zE')][./td/div/div/div/span[contains(.,'text')]]//div[@role='checkbox']
```